# Why repeat the last verse of "Yoshev b'Seter Elyon"

Tags: tehilim-psalms, motzei-shabbos, nusach-ashkenaz, nusach-ari, pesukei-dezimra

In Nusach ashkenaz, as well as in "V'hi Noam" of Nusach haAri, the last pasuk of "Yoshev B'seter Elyon" (Psalm 91) is repeated.

Why is that?

Comment: Also in so-called _nusach S'farad_.

Comment: @msh210, I have too little experience with either Sepharad, Sfard, or Edot Hamizrach to comment on them.

Comment: The Abudraham gives a reason, but it is predicated on also repeating the verse V'hi Noam, which is not in Nusach Ari (I don't know about other Nuschaot): http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=26840&pgnum=96

Comment: @Menachem, nor in Nusach Ashkenaz

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Machzor Vitri - page 114](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14643&st=&pgnum=322&hilite=) says we say the verse Orech Yamim twice in order to complete the name of Hashem that is produced by doing so. וכופלין אורך ימים כדי להשלים השם היוצא ממנו

[Tashbatz 258](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4087&st=&pgnum=37&hilite=), Maharam says we say it twice this way it has the numerical value of Kohanim, since the Chashmonoim when they went to war said 7 times Vyehi Noam and twice Orech Yamim and were victorious.

[Avudraham](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=26840&pgnum=96) says it is a protection of the 248 Aivorim.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43644/why-repeat-the-last-verse-of-yoshev-bseter-elyon?noredirect=1#comment113331_43644

Answer (score 3):

A late answer, I know, but a different one (and, I must say that I still don't understand some of the claims made in the other answer so this one is as reasonable, but I can't find a source for it).

The Birnbaum siddur Hasiddur Hashalem writes (page 310):

> ארך ימים is repeated so that the number of verses of this psalm reach a total of seventeen, the numerical value of טוב

Though, based on some of the answers to [my](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/63932/repeated-final-line-in-psalm-150/63957#63957) question, one wonders if the repetition isn't because of the "completion of a section" -- we have just had 2 sequential psalms (90 and 91), (at least) 3 psalms in a row with a particular theme (being saved/protected/given shelter from threats via closeness to God) and are about to begin 2 other sequential psalms which shift the theme and are litanies of praise. Just a thought.