# Repeated final line in Psalm 150

Tags: tefilla, tehilim-psalms

During *Pesukei D'zimra*, we say a series of chapters from *Tehillim*. When we recite chapter [150](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16371#v=6),  the final *pasuk* (*kol haneshama*...) is said twice. The ArtScroll Machzor (unlike the everyday ArtScroll siddur, which is silent on the subject) says,

> "Having now concluded the six psalms that are the main part of *Pesukei
>   D'zimrah*, we repeat the last verse to signify that this section has
>   come to an end (*Avudraham*)."

Is there any other time in *davening* where a "section comes to an end" so we double up a *pasuk* to signify that?

Comment: +1 I was going to cite Art Scroll, but u did. I agree, that this seems to warrant a better answer. I'll research Beurei Hatefilah tomorrow. It may have something on this.

Comment: Hashem Yimloch at the end of the Shira.

Comment: @DoubleAA, sounds like an answer, if you can cite that we double it to mark the end.

Comment: It should be noted that Siddur *Kawanat HaLev* states that we repeat the pasuq "so that others will not be able to say about Israel that they hurry to finish". This is stated in the name of HaRaD"A.

Comment: @DoubleAA How does that complete anything? While we also say the Targum there, the next line is the next verse (15:19). After Tehillim 150 we move into 3 assorted verses from other Psalms and then Divrei Hayamim.

Comment: Danno That's all a later kabbalistic addition not found in early siddurim.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you -- the ArtScroll only mentions that the addition of the Aramaic is from the Ari Z"L so I assumed that the rest was all inserted at the same time.

Comment: את הפסוקים כל הנשמה תהלל יה, שהוא סוף פסוקי דזמרא, אומרים פעמיים (טור או"ח סי' נ"א). הסיבה לכך היא דבריו של ר' יוסי 'יהי חלקי עם גומרי הלל בכל יום' (שבת קי"ח). רצה לומר שמסיימים את ספר תהילים המבוסס על הללויה, ואם לא יכפיל את הפסוק האחרון, לא ייראה כמסיים. 
מסיבה זו כופלים בשירת הים את הפסוק 'ה' ימלוך לעולם ועד' שהוא סיום הקטע ויושע ה' (מנהגי מהרי"ל הל' תפילה).http://www.daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/value.asp?id1=1413

Comment: @GershonGold so that confirms what DoubleAA said, with source, and gives the reason. It should be a fine answer to my question. Thank you (though I have to admit his logic seems unclear to me - לא ייראה כמסיים, and finishing a keta as opposed to finishing anything else).

Comment: We also say Orech Yamim Asbiyehu V'areihu biyshuati twice as well as several verses in Hallel

Comment: @CashCow is the reasoning the same?

Comment: With Hallel maybe although we repeat a lot of them. It's the last few verses of a section of Tehillim. With Yoshev B'seter I don't know. We repeat it too on Motzei Shabbat not just Psukdei D'zimra.

Comment: @msh210 ShA OC 51:7

Answer (score 2):

As I often find, [Beurei Hatefillah](http://www.beureihatefila.com/files/Which_Chapters_Of_Tehillim_Comprise_Pseukei_D_Zimra.pdf) has an answer: Citing *Machzor Vitri* ch. 1:

> This is the reason that we repeat the last line of Tehillim: Kol
>   Hanishama T’Hallel Yah Halleluya. It is based on what we learned in
>   Tractate Shabbos that we should be among those who complete Hallel
>   each day. This means that we should read the last chapters of Tehillim
>   each day which are the chapters that all begin with the word
>   Halleluya. If we did not repeat the last sentence of the last chapter
>   of Tehillim, we would not appear to have completed the last chapter.
>   We would make it appear that there were additional verses that follow.
>   However, now that we read the last verse twice, we demonstrate that it
>   is the last verse and we have completed the last chapter of Tehillim.

The English translation is at the end of the article on pp. 31-32. I recommend that you read most of the article from the beginning, as it discusses a debate on which Tehillim comprise *Psukei Dezimra* in the first place. Understanding that debate will provide some context on why this is considered "the end" and will provide further context on Art Scroll's comment, as well. (IMO, Art Scroll's comment could use a bit of "improvement", esp. considering that they are not exactly lacking in "space".)

Comment: My concern with this is the same as with the comment made by Gershon Gold -- "we would not appear to have completed the last chapter". I don't understand that.

Comment: is the repetition to indicate we are completing sefer Tehillim, or a section of davening (the "main part of Pesukei D'zimra")?

Comment: @Danno If you read the article, it seems that the importance is to indicate the end of Tehillim. See the article as to the debate as to whether that is also considered the end of *Psukei Dezimra*. I think that's a secondary point, here.

Comment: According to the article is the issue the completing of a hallel which coincidentally is made of those 6 chapters, or of completing sefer tehillim wherever it is found? If I read 150 as part of something else, and finish it, I am "finishing" sefer tehillim also. Do I double the last line? The haftorah for Yom Kippur mincha is an entire book. Do we double the last line? (bad example -- extra verses added from Micha, but the general question is the same)

Comment: @Danno Interesting question. I'm inclined to say that it's a bit of both, and moreso, b/c there's an apparent mitzvah to complete "Hallel" each day as part of Psukei D'zimrah. It may be more "coincidental" that we follow the opinion that "Hallel" means "Haleluyah" i.e. the last chapters of Tehillim. Related to some of your other comments, I'm not sure what occurs in Hallel Hamitzri as to why we double up, and "Orech Yamim". There must be different reasons for those. I'll see if I discover anything on that.