# Why is "Hashem Yimloch L'Olam Va'ed" repeated in Az Yashir?

Tags: sources-mekorot, prayer-book

The phrase "Hashem yimloch l'olam va'ed" (G-d will reign forever and ever) is repeated once in the paragraph of Az Yashir in the siddur. Why is this so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is repeated at the end of the Song of the Sea to indicate the end of the song. (OC 51:7)

Comment: Similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/63932/repeated-final-line-in-psalm-150