# Why is "Hashem... l'olam va'ed" repeated after Tehillim 30?

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, nusach-sefard, arizal

In Nusach Sfard, why is the phrase "Hashem Melech; Hashem Malach; Hashem yimloch l'olam va'ed" repeated in the paragraph after Tehillim 30?<sup>*</sup> I've heard it has everything to do with the writings of the Arizal, but I'm not sure.

This question is unique to Nusach Sfard and the Sephardi nusachot, in somewhat of a follow-up to [my previous question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89188/why-is-there-an-aramaic-line-after-hashem-yimloch-lolam-vaed-in-az-yashir) regarding the phrase's repetition in "Az Yashir".

<sup>* "Mizmor shir chanukat habayit l'David..." You can see what I'm talking about [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Sefard,_Weekday_Shacharit,_Hodu.7-10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).</sup>

Comment: I believe that even outside of this specific repetition, and Nusach Ashkenaz, this verse is the one said most often during the day. There must be something extremely important about saying this verse, in particular. Just a hunch that this may play a factor to answering the question.

Comment: It's there in all Mizrachi and Italian minhagim. I suppose it should be something older than Arizal, but it's just a guess...

Comment: related: https://www.ykr.org.il/question/9490

Comment: The [*Beis Yosef*](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x134) gives a reason for it, but I don't understand it, so I'll just leave it here as a link.

Comment: @DanF, it's actually a combination of three pesukim. Ezra, they also repeat this at Bevis Marks in London, so I would suspect that it's not Lurianic.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt "it's actually a combination of three pesukim" - I think you're referring to "H Melech, H Malach, H Yimloch". This copmbo is said far less often than the full *pasuk* mentioned in this question. It is said twice in *Shira*, in *Hodu* (beginning of *Psukei*), in *Uva Letzion* and end of *Aleinu*.

Comment: @DanF What Noach means to say is that the phrase is a combo of three passukim. You won't find H' Melech, H' Malach, H' Yimloch L'Olam Va'ed anywhere in the Tanach. :)

Comment: @ezra OOPS! I didn't focus on the beginning of your question, in that you were referring to the combo. Sorry...

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt But we have a [time-honored tradition](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tractate_Soferim.14.8) of treating it like a _pasuk_.

Answer (score 1):

The Ben Ish Chai writes ([Year 1, Vayigash, par. 1](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A9_%D7%97%D7%99_%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%99%D7%92%D7%A9#.D7.90)) that the reason it is repeated is to crown *Hashem* as king over the body and the soul.

Comment: Refer to my comment to OP. Could this be the motivation as to why this verse is said most often throughout the day, but esp, during Shacharit? In trying to understand your answer, does he mean once for the body and a second time for the soul?

Comment: @DanF Could be. Note also that he says it's "*al derech*" (similar) to saying "*Hashem Hu Ha'Elokim*" twice as mentioned in Nach.

Comment: @DanF For your second question, yes. Or perhaps the fact of saying it twice signifies both, not necessarily one for each.