# Qriat Shema Al Hamita, mizmorim

Tags: shema, nusach-ashkenaz, hamapil, nusach-edot-hammizrach

In Gemara [Shevuot 15b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shevuot.15b.10), they explain how is the process to extend the surface of Yerushalaim and its Qedusha. One of the things is to recite the Psalm 91 up to the word Machsi (see hagahot Hagra, see Abudarham who says that they are 60 words) and an other mizmor (a part of Tehilim 3). Subsequently, the Gemara says that Rabbi Yehoshua Ben Levi said those Psalms when he gets to sleep.

In [Bet Yosef OC 239](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%98#%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3), this Gemara is quoted. But in SA he doesn't write to stop the Mizmor after the word Machsi. I checked the Nuschaot of QS Al Hamita for Sefaradim and Ashkenazim. Sefaradim make as it's written in Gemara and Ashkenazim recite the whole Mizmor.

What is the source of those who don't follow the Gemara?

Comment: [Do you know this Divine name interpretation?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/90202/15256)

Comment: ..?????? @Kazi bacsi

Comment: I don't understand precisely what do you mean, but by saying the whole Psalm 91 with the additional verse and the repetition, you allude to a Divine name, which serves as a protection against evil forces. It's a different idea.

Comment: Yes I understand but the Gemara is clear and poskim I soon don't address the question

Comment: If it’s שיר של נגעים then presumably you say past כי אתה ה מחסי

Comment: The Beis Yosef there quotes the entire posuk, until מעונך. It's true that the Gra there cites several rishonim who omit the last three words, but the Beis Yosef may just have been following the Gemara as printed (or felt that when the rishonim say עד כי אתה ה' מחסי, they mean until the end of that posuk).

Comment: @Meir it's not relevant, even following this Girsa they don't say the entire mizmor

Comment: My point was that those who say the whole posuk are indeed relying on the girsa as in the printed Gemara (and as the Beis Yosef cites it). Edos Hamizrach do indeed stop at מחסי, presumably following the Rif and Rosh's version.

Comment: If the question is whence the source to say the entire mizmor - it's probably by analogy with Motzaei Shabbos (and indeed one of the reasons we say it then is because of פגעים).

Comment: It's indeed the question. I followed the Gra to explain that the minhag sfaradi follows his Girsa, from Rif and En Yaakov

Comment: BTW, Rashi comments in the gemara: להני קראי - שיר של פגעים. I understand this as the whole psalm, and it seems that Ashkenazim followed his view.